# Backbone + Require with Backbone.localStorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage, requirejs

I am building an app with Backbone and RequireJS, using [this](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/build-backbone-apps-using-requirejs/) as a guide. Since Backbone is non-AMD, I am using the RequireJS shim, as described in the guide I mentioned above.

My main script looks like this:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "js/",
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery.min',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone',
    'backbone.localStorage': 'lib/backbone.localStorage-min'
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'backbone.localStorage': {
      deps: ['backbone'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  }
});
```

The guide shows to include 'backbone.localStorage' in other modules without including Backbone, so I assumed that either `deps: ['backbone']` or `exports: Backbone` in the localStorage shim made sure that Backbone was included.

However, I keep getting an `undefined method: extend` error in the Javascript console

I am starting other modules like this:

`define(['underscore','backbone.localStorage'], function(_, Backbone) {`

How do I include both Backbone and Backbone.localStorage with RequireJS?

This is my first time using either Backbone or RequireJS, so I apologize if my problem is obvious...

Comment: It may not have an effect but I'm pretty sure your localStorage backbone shim shouldn't have an export, it just attaches itself to Backbone

Answer (score 2):

Here is my coffee-script version:

```
shim:
 underscore:
  exports: "_"
 backbone:
  deps: ["underscore", "jquery"]
  exports: "Backbone"
 localStorage:
  deps: ["backbone"]

paths:
  backbone: "lib/backbone/backbone-min"
  underscore: "lib/underscore/underscore-min"
  localStorage: "lib/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage"
```

and then in a module

```
define [
 "underscore"
 "backbone"
 "localStorage"
], (_, Backbone) ->
```

Local storage basically attaches itself to the Backbone object so backbone just has to be loaded by AMD before it.

Comment: What if you are defining router in the module, then something has to be assigned to local storage no? I have router being defined after

Comment: I don't understand your question - post a new question, along with sample code and I can look at it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462114/how-to-make-use-of-the-data-when-calling-fetch-on-it