# How to make use of the data when calling fetch on it?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I am using require.js with backbone and backbone.localstorage and I am trying to figure out how to make use of the data after calling fetch, not sure how to go about it... I am trying to pass the data into my view and make use of it.

Here is the example of the data stored in localstorage:

```
[{"artist":"Hits 1 Entertainment 4-1-1","title":"Hear Katy's Perry's New Album!"}, ...]
```

So it is objects within an array.

This is my code for backbone...

```
var songz = new Songs();
songz.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
songz.fetch({dataType: 'json'});
var songV = new SongV({collection: songz});
songV.render();
```

Songs is a collection, that looks like this in the collections file, SongV is the view for each song.

Here is the view with the code above included:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/song',
  'collections/songs',
  'views/song',
  'text!templates/page.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, Song, Songs, SongV, PageT){ 

  var Page = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#page"),
    render: function () { 
      this.$el.html( PageT );

      var songz = new Songs();
      songz.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
      songz.fetch({dataType: 'json'});
      var songV = new SongV({collection: songz});
      songV.render();



    }


  });
    return Page;
});
```

Here is the collection file:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/song',
], function($, _, Backbone, Song){

    var Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Song,

    initialize: function () {
    }
    });
  return Songs;
});
```

Here is the model file:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({

  });
  return Song;
});
```

Here is the template file:

```
<tr>
    <th> Number </th>
    <th> Title </th>
    <th> Artist </th>
    <th> Date_Added </th>
    <th> Video </th>
</tr>
  <% _.each(songs, function(song){ %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= song.get("number") %> </td>
    <td> <%= song.get("title") %> </td>
    <td> <%= song.get("artist") %> </td>
    <td> <%= song.get("added_on") %> </td>
    <td> <%= song.get("video") %> </td>
  </tr>
  <% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch and then bind to the reset event on the collection to see when it was successfully pulled the data from the server.

```
Page = Backbone.View.extend
 el: $('#page')
 render: ->
  songz = new Songs()
  # Initialize view
  songV = new SongV({collection: songz})
  # Render view
  songV.render()
  # Fetch collection
  songz.fetch()

SongV = Backbone.View.extend
  initialize: ->
    @listenTo @collection, "reset", @onReset
  onReset: (collection) ->
    # Use populated collection data
    ...

Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend
  model: Song
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("music")
  initialize: ->
```

This is how Backbone.LocalStorage stores the collections and models --> [here](http://blog.mostlystatic.com/2013/01/minimal-backbonelocalstorage-example.html)
See the table at the bottom, the key for the chain block is you local storage name and then each model has a unique key.

So this means if you have data sitting in local storage that you have put there yourself, you should take it out with a cross-browser local storage device like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) and then use it to populate your Backbone.Collection.

Alternatively, you could fetch from the server (recommended) and that will populate your collection. Or you could [bootstrap](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) the data on page load and reset your collection that way.

Comment: Anyway you can edit that to regular javascript : / I will learn coffeescript soon enough but it is a bit hard to make sense of that...